# DNN 8 Installation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dotnetnuke, sql-server-2012-express

I have been trying to setup a dev. environment of DNN8 on my system. On installation wizard page, its keep giving DB connection error mentioned below.

**Database Information: Unable to connect to database.
Database Connection Error ERROR: Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 20
Number: 2
Message:**

I guess it has nothing to do with folder permission but its DB problem. I have SQL SERVER 2012 express edition installed. My system in on domain. Maybe it has something to do with that, I don't know.

I followed every step in the following video by Chris Hammond on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOoQJDeTlJ0

except changing the name "dnndev.me" with something else.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Express, with the default "instance" settings, don't "configure" the DB settings, leave them as the DEFAULT settings on the setup wizard and it should work from there.

If you renamed the instance name, then you will need to customize the settings.